# flash as3 - stack overflow error in case / switch statement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, stack, switch-statement

Wow - I'm kind of excited - I get a stack overflow error. I'm not sure why though...

This is my code:

```
switch (direction) {
    case "left" :

        if (project_array[cp].projectThumb.thumbActive == false){
            if (cp>0){ cp--; }
            checkActive("left")
        } else {
            unloadProject();
        }
    break;
    case "right" :
        if (project_array[cp].projectThumb.thumbActive == false){
            if (cp<(tp-1)){ cp++; }
            checkActive("right")
        } else {
            unloadProject();
        }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I was confused for a while, how your code calls error on stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to a compiler bug, normally you can avoid it enclosing your case content with {} =>

```
switch (direction) {
    case "left" :
    { // --> here
        if (project_array[cp].projectThumb.thumbActive == false){
            if (cp>0){ cp--; }
            checkActive("left")
        } else {
            unloadProject();
        }
    } // -> and here
    break;
    case "right" : 
    { // --> here
        if (project_array[cp].projectThumb.thumbActive == false){
            if (cp<(tp-1)){ cp++; }
            checkActive("right")
        } else {
            unloadProject();
        }
    } // -> and here
    break;
}
```

Comment: strange - thanks. Is it bad form to have so many nested ifs in a case statement? I didn't really know a better way to do that without sending it to separate functions.

Comment: Wow, really? I've never seen this, and I use switches fairly frequently. What triggers the bug? @mheavers - w/r/t your nested ifs, cleaner code is always better. That is a bit tricky to visually parse - but it may well be the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do. You might consider pulling out a few of those expressions and storing them in variables - var thumbActive = project_array[cp].projectThumb.thumbActive, etc. Just makes for easier reading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was a bug at the time of the last response, but as of today it's considered a code convention in flex:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions